# "Internet Explorer has modified this page to help prevent cross-site scripting" for iframe

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, iframe, cross-domain

I place on a page with a one domain iframe that pointing to another domain. Everything works fine. Then I send to iframe form by **POST** method, when it comes the reply, Internet Explorer generates an error

```
Internet Explorer has modified this page to help prevent cross-site scripting
```

When I send a form by **GET** all works fine.

Why does the issue occur? How can I fix it? Can I fix it, if i do not have access to the page that hosts the iframe?

Comment: Are you asking how to get around security measures in web browsers?

Comment: I think the answer is "no". I try to use the quite legal method postMessage for a cross-domain communication. Script works fine in FF and Chrome. But IE produce that issue.

Answer (score 0):

Usually this happens when something in the request is also in the response. For instance:

```
http://example.com/somepage?name=%3Cscript%3Ealert(%22lol%20hax%22%2Bdocument.cookie)%3B%3C%2Fscript%3E
```

So this problem depends entirely on *what* you are POSTing to the iframe. You should probably avoid using cross-domain iframes anyway as a general rule.

Comment: It seems to be true. I actually send to iframe content that contains tags and there are may be scripts. But output doesn't contain any scripts. Can i prevent issue by sending X-XSS-Protection in iframe?

Answer (score 0):

Old question I know, but Niet is right about the issue.  The solution is to enable CORS for that particular page.  A full breakdown: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/

For PHP, the solution I used is:

```
$http_protocolPos = stripos($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'], '/');
$http_protocol = strtolower(substr($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'], 0, $http_protocolPos)).'://'; 
$http_serverName = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
$httpFull = $http_protocol . $http_serverName;

if ($httpFull == "{$http_protocol}www.example1.com" || $httpFull == "{$http_protocol}www.example2.com" || 
    $httpFull == "{$http_protocol}localhost" )
{  
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: $httpFull");
}
```

From Microsoft's documentation, this may work as well:

header("X-XSS-Protection: 0");

But I am only guessing on that one.